# Using fewer bytes to store data - 8051

Tags: memory, optimization, storage, 8051, rom

I'm currently working on code for the 8051 processor, and I'm trying to figure out better ways to store data in immediate RAM without using so many bytes of rom space. The data is mostly random but sometimes some data is null.

For example, I have a device connected to my chip that expects 7 bytes of data for processing. Let's say I want to send to that device the following data:

```
 12h 34h 56h 41h 33h 77h 00h
```

The quick way for me to do this is something like the following:

```
 DATABLOCK equ 30h
 MOV DATABLOCK,#12h
 MOV DATABLOCK+1,#34h
 MOV DATABLOCK+2,#56h
 MOV DATABLOCK+3,#41h
 MOV DATABLOCK+4,#33h
 MOV DATABLOCK+5,#77h
 MOV DATABLOCK+6,#00h
```

I refer to the following website for instructions:
http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/is51/is51_mov.htm

and based on my code, I needed 21 bytes to store that in rom. One byte for MOV, one byte for destination (DATABLOCK+x) and one byte for the value (xxh). multiply total by 7 = 21.

The problem is, I use this kind of command frequently because its fast but I have limited free space on the chip.

I thought of the following but it doesn't really help. Heck, I think it takes an EXTRA two bytes:

```
 DATABLOCK equ 30h
 MOV R0,#DATABLOCK
 MOV @R0,#12h
 INC R0
 MOV @R0,#34h
 INC R0
 MOV @R0,#56h
 INC R0
 MOV @R0,#41h
 INC R0
 MOV @R0,#33h
 INC R0
 MOV @R0,#77h
 INC R0
 MOV @R0,#00h
```

And then I thought of this which can get crazy which I think takes even MORE bytes:

```
 DATABLOCK equ 30h
 mov R1,SP
 MOV SP,#DATABLOCK-1
 MOV A,#12h
 PUSH ACC
 MOV A,#34h
 PUSH ACC
 MOV A,#56h
 PUSH ACC
 MOV A,#41h
 PUSH ACC
 MOV A,#33h
 PUSH ACC
 MOV A,#77h
 PUSH ACC
 MOV A,#00h ;could use CLR A but what if value isn't 0h?
 PUSH ACC
 MOV SP,R1
```

Now the problem is I don't have that much ram either so I can't afford to keep the same values in ram for the entire program. If I could, I would implement code like this:

```
 FIND12H equ 70h
 FIND34H equ 60h
 FIND56H equ 50h
 FIND41H equ 55h
 FIND33H equ 66h
 FIND77H equ 22h
 FIND00H equ 2Ah
 DATABLOCK equ 30h
 mov R1,SP
 MOV SP,#DATABLOCK-1
 PUSH FIND12H
 PUSH FIND34H
 PUSH FIND56H
 PUSH FIND41H
 PUSH FIND33H
 PUSH FIND77H
 PUSH FIND00H
 MOV SP,R1
```

Now that code there would only cost me maybe 12 bytes. That's a savings of about 9 bytes (like over 1/3), but the problem is I'm using absolute values, not memory locations. Like if the following worked with the 8051, then my question would be answered:

```
 mov A,SP
 MOV SP,#DATABLOCK-1
 PUSH #12h
 PUSH #34h
 PUSH #56h
 PUSH #41h
 PUSH #33h
 PUSH #77h
 PUSH #0h
 MOV SP,A
```

But for the push command, the parameter cannot be a hard-coded value.

So given what all I have presented, How can I use fewer rom bytes to store data into internal memory?

Answer (score 0):

"For example, I have a device connected to my chip that expects 7 bytes of data for processing" Why you need the data in RAM? You can copy the data right from ROM. For example if you want to send data via UART (not checked if work):

```
sendData:
MOV   DPTR, constData   ;pointer to data in ROM
MOV   R0, #7            ;number of data to send
sendMore: 
MOVC  A, @DPTR          ;move data to accumulator
MOV   SBUF, A           ;send data via UART
JNB   TI, $             ;wait for TI flag
CLR   TI                ;clear TI flag
INC   DPTR              ;increment pointer
DJNZ  R0, sendMore      ;decrement couter and jump if not zero

constData: DB #12h, #34h, #56h, #41h, #33h, #77h, #00h ;constants stored in ROM
```

If you really want the data in RAM you can use memory copy function which looks something like this:

```
ARRAY_START equ 30h
ARRAY_LEN   equ 7h

MOV   R0, ARRAY_START  ;set pointer to start array
MOV   DPTR, SrcTable   ;pointer to data in ROM
copyMore:
MOVC  A, @DPTR         ;move data to acumulator
MOV   @R0, A           ;move data to RAM destination
INC   DPTR             ;increment source pointer
INC   R0               ;increment destination pointer
CJNE  R0, ARRAY_START+ARRAY_LEN, copyMore


SrcTable: DB #12h, #34h, #56h, #41h, #33h, #77h, #00h ;constants stored in ROM
```